# How did Spider-Man come to be working for the Future Foundation?

Tags: comics, marvel, spider-man, fantastic-four

So I've been away from Spider-Man for best bit of a decade and am still trying to catch up after my other half brought me 'The Death of Spider-Man' the other month... although I believe that is Ultimate Universe (1610?) Spider-Man.

Picked up an X-Men other day, opened it, and Spider-Man was on a boat helping the X-Men with some new possibly borrowed technology, dressed in a white suit?!

I think he mentioned he was working with Fantastic 4/the 'Future Foundation' now? Can anyone give me a brief history of how he has come to join a team or why he has donned this cool new white suit? And maybe some essential issues I may want to acquire.

Comment: For how long have you been away from Spidey exactly ? Because if you missed Civil War, you have quite a bit to catch up :P

Comment: I've read parts of Civil War and know about him chosing to register ect. The last time I really read Spider-man was the when Kain was still trying to kill Scarlet-spider. But am familiar with events up to 'Secret Invasion' I believe. I also believe my question and this comment all take place in the 616 universe/mainstream universe (Amazing/Spectacular ect).

Comment: "my other half brought me 'The death of Spider-man' the other month...although I believe that is Ultimate Universe (1610?) spider man." - [The Ultimate Universe Peter Parker died in 2011](http://marvel.com/news/story/14648/death_of_spider-man). [The 616-Universe Peter Parker "died" late last year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dying_Wish).

Comment: "Spider-man on a boat helping the X-men with some new possibly borrowed technology, dressed in a white suit?!" Presumably attempting to ride the coattails of the [I'm on a boat](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7yfISlGLNU) meme.

Answer (score 8):

I realize it's nearly a year, but someone might come across this in the future.

Following the events of *Fantastic Four: Three* where the Human Torch was believed dead, the *Fantastic Four* title was rebooted as *FF* (Future Foundation). It is in this story arc that Spider-Man joins the FF and gains the white suit. All these stories are part of Jonathan Hickman's long run on the title. The relevant issues are:

- *Dark Reign: Fantastic Four* #1-5
- *Fantastic Four* vol. 1 #570-588 <-- the last few issues of this are the *Three* storyline
- *FF* vol. 1 #1-11 <-- the first 2-3 issues are where Spidey joins
- *Fantastic Four* vol. 1 #600-611 & *FF* vol. 1 #12-23, alternating issues

It's a great run, you should check it out.

Comment: “I realize it's nearly a year, but someone might come across this in the future.” Quite right, that’s the idea of the site. Excellent first answer, welcome to Stack Exchange.